# How to fade out a subview to show a UIViewController's view loaded from a .nib

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I have ViewController which is loaded from a .nib file. in the viewDidLoad method I create a subview and add it to the view hierarchy. How do I fade out that subview to show the view in .nib file?

(the subview is like a splash screen, which I want to fade out to show the view in the .nib, it's set up this way since it was easiest way for me.)

Here is some of my code (I tried to set a reference to the original view from the nib in the viewDidLoad but couldn't get it to work):

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
NSLog(@"View did load");
//set reference to view in .nib here
UIView *currentView = self.view;

CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
splashView = [[splashView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[[self view] addSubview:splashView];
//transition did not work

[UIView transitionFromView:splashView toView:currentView duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"transition finished");
}];

}
```

That code crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked in to using storyboard/segues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in place of your original code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
NSLog(@"View did load");

CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
splashView = [[splashView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[[self view] addSubview:splashView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront: splashView];

[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0
                     delyay: 0.5 // omit if you don't need a delay
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut // check the documentation for other options
                 animations: ^{ 
                    splashView.alpha = 0;
                 } 
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                    [splashView removeFromSuperView];
                 }];
```

I don't know if you're using ARC or not, or if you using storyboards or not!
If you're note using ARC, then memory management is wrong in this snippet.

Comment: I didn't use storyboards because some of the literature I've read said that storyboards, while easy to use, tend to confuse beginners from learning some of the core concepts. I am using iOS 6 and ARC. 

Thanks Nenad M that worked perfectly. How is the memory management wrong in the snippet?

Comment: Hi! If you're using ARC then you're good to go with the provided sample. In non-ARC code yo would have to release/autorelease the splashView in some point of time.